# My app can't receive BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast

Tags: android, bootcompleted

I am working on an app which needs receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast when the device boots. 
According to the documents in Android Developers, I already know that since android 3.1, apps that never run after installing or force killed by user will not receive the boot broadcast when device boots, so with the rules, how can I receive boot broadcast? By the way, I have already tried open my app when boot is finished, but it is still not working.

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.guoyonghui.todo"
          android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:name=".BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".tasks.TasksActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".taskdetail.TaskDetailActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".addedittask.AddEditTaskActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".statistics.StatisticsActivity"/>

        <receiver android:name=".alarm.AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.guoyonghui.todo.alarm.ACTION_TASK_ALARM"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".alarm.BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        Toast.makeText(context, action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", action);

        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action)) {
            TasksRepository tasksRepository = TasksRepository.getInstance(TasksLocalDataSource.getInstance(context));
            List<Task> tasks = tasksRepository.loadTasks();
            for (Task task : tasks) {
                if (task.isActive()) {
                    AlarmReceiver.setAlarm(context, task);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an app that never fails to receive BOOT_COMPLETED, however the difference is that I don't have the `category.DEFAULT` action in my intent filters. Maybe you could try this?

Comment: @Guomato, do you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use the Default category in this case. According to the documentation of this category, it is used for the following purpose:

> Set if the **activity** should be an option for the default action (center press) to perform on a piece of data. Setting this will hide from the user any activities without it set when performing an action on some data. Note that this is normally -not- set in the Intent when initiating an action -- it is for use in intent filters specified in packages. (Emphasis mine)

See the list of categories and what they're for here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: "Not working" as in it doesn't get called at all or it does get called and it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: The receiver doesn't get called after device boots